# Multiple instances in one form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Trying to implement poll-creating system, where I can create questions with choices (previously I did this all in the admin, and had to create an individual choice object for every choice)

Here's  my models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    has_answered = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Vote")
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

So right now here's the template:

```
<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ question_form.question_text }}
    <br><br>
    <!--{{ choice_form.choice_text|placeholder:"Choice" }}-->
    <input class="choice" name="choice_text" placeholder="Choice" type="text" />
    <input class="choice" name="choice_text" placeholder="Choice" type="text" />
    <input class="choice" name="choice_text" placeholder="Choice" type="text" />

    <img src="{% static 'images/plus.png' %}" class="add_choice" />
    <br>

    <button class="submit" type="submit">Create question</button>


</form>
```

As you can see I'm not sure whether using multiple `{{ choice_form.choice_text|placeholder:"Choice" }}` is possible. So I paste multiple input fields and tried to get all of them by using `getList()`. However I get this error:

```
'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'getList'
```

Any idea why? Here's my views:

```
def questions(request):
    question_form = QuestionForm(request.POST or None)
    choice_form = ChoiceForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST:
        choice = request.POST.getList('choice_text')
        print(choice)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if question_form.is_valid():
            print('valid question')
            #question = question_form.save(commit=False)

    return render(request, 'questions.html', {'question_form': question_form, 'choice_form': choice_form})
```

So how exactly should I go about this, for grabbing every choice input? Eventually I want to make all these choices map to the question that was entered. But as I said I'm sure sure whether it's possible to have multiple instances of the same field in one form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `getlist` instead of `getList`.

Also consider using [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/), specifically the [MultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) could be useful in your scenario.